# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x(\cos(y)-1)}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The problem is stated as:

> Find $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x(\cos(y)-1)}{x^2+y^2}$

**My attempt**

First of all, we use the fact that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(y) - 1}{y} = 0$

We expand by $y$ in the denominator and numerator in our original expression, and we get that:

$\frac{\cos(y)-1}{y}\cdot\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Now, I want to show that $xy / (x^2+y^2)$ is bounded somehow, in order to show that the limit tends to $0$. I'm thinking of using the fact that $\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$, but I couldn't get any further from there.

I recently started multivariable calculus, so I'd be glad if you could explain how to show that a multivariable function is bounded above, and whether it's solvable using the GM-AM inequality.

Thank you.

Comment: You mostly have it; consider the fact that $xy \leq \max(x^2,y^2)$ and that should show your bound.

Comment: By CBS, $x^2+y^2 \ge 2|xy|$.

Comment: In fact, substituting $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$, we get the second term is $1/2 \sin(2\theta)$, and the bound of $1/2$ holds.

Comment: For example, you can use the fact that $\lvert x \rvert \leq (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ and $\lvert y \rvert \leq (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, so $\lvert \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} \rvert \leq 1$